# get_or_create not creating object from POST form

Tags: python, django

Trying to create an object with get_or_create(). The response hits, but it never successfully creates the object.

Python code:

```
class Note(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     topic = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
     type = models.ForeignKey(NoteType, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.topic

def post(request):
     topic = request.POST['topic']
     user = request.user 
     content = request.POST['content']
     note_type = request.POST['type']

     note, created = Note.objects.get_or_create(user=user, topic=topic, content=content, type=note_type)

     return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

So the exception constantly hits and never creates the object. Urls are fine and I'm importing the model. Any reason why this object isn't being created? Theres no errors, it just redirects as normal.

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/post/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'notes')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\Alana\project-fridge\notes\views.py" in post_note
  34.       note, created = Note.objects.get_or_create(user=user, topic=topic, content=content, type=note_type)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get_or_create
  146.         return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get_or_create
  470.             return self.get(**lookup), False
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  379.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  655.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  673.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1266.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_filter
  1197.                 connector)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in add
  71.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in prepare
  339.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in get_prep_lookup
  143.             return self._pk_trace(value, 'get_prep_lookup', lookup_type)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in _pk_trace
  216.         v = getattr(field, prep_func)(lookup_type, v, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  322.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  555.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /post/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'text'
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: @AdamKG returns `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'text'`.. ?

Comment: @Modelesq Update the question with your current code, and include the full traceback (there should be a "switch to copy/paste view" in the error page).

Comment: OK, problem is that Note.type is a foreign key, and you're trying to assign a string, "text". Please include the model definitions of both Note and whatever it FKs into.

Comment: @AdamKG updated again. also how did you know it had to do with a foreign key?

Comment: You missed including NoteType. Let's cut to the chase tho: `note_type_str = request.POST[whatever]`, `note_type = NoteType.objects.get(name=note_type_str)`. `name` might need to be some other field if that's not what you called it. And to answer your question, I'm a wizard. (... j/k, recognized the traceback, been using django for years :D)

Comment: @AdamKG you're awesome. Make an answer and I'll mark it correct! :D

Comment: Any reason you're not using a ModelForm for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are storing a list of various Note Types in the NoteType model...

To make this code work, you are first going to need to get one of them from that model and then set use that when creating your new note

```
note_type = request.POST['type']

note_type_orm = NoteType.objects.get(type=note_type)

note, created = Note.objects.get_or_create(user=user, topic=topic, content=content, type=note_type_orm)
```

Notice the change in the get_or_create that I am now using the note_type_orm and not just the note_type (which is just a string)